# Please explain how this permutation algorithm works and also how this palindrome algorithm works

Tags: c, algorithm

So how this function is suppose to work is if n2 is a permutation of n1 its suppose to return 1. n2 is a permutation of n1 if it can be formed by rearranging the digits of n1. (I.E. 237654 is a permutation of 743526).

I don't understand what is going on if somebody could explain line by line I would appreciate it, thank you.

```
int is_permutation_division (unsigned long n1, unsigned long n2) 

{
    int a[10] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    size_t i;

    while (n1 != 0)
    {
        a[n1 % 10]++; // Edit: little syntax error
        n1 /= 10;
    }

    while (n2 != 0)
    {
        a[n2 %10]--;
        n2 /= 10;
    }

    for (i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        if (a[i] != 0)
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1; 
}
```

This next function tests whether a string is a palindrome or not. A word is a palindrome if its the same when its spelled backwards (i.e. race car rac ecar)

I have a question about one line that I have commented on. I just want to know if its j-1 because you don't want to process the null character

```
int is_palindrome(const char s[])

{
size_t i,j;

for (i=0; j<strlen(s); i<j; i++; j--)
{
    if(s[i] != s[j-1]) /*is it j-1 because you don't want to check the null character? */
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
return 1;
}
```

Comment: Yes, its because you don't want to check the null character.

Comment: I think there is typo in the first while it should be `]` not `)`

Comment: I don't think that the first algorithm (check if it is permutation) is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The palindrome is indeed to avoid checking the null character.

Answer (score 0):

```
while (n1 != 0)
{
    a[n1 % 10]++; // adds one to the array position of last digit. i.e: 42235 -> a[5] goes up by 1.
    n1 /= 10; //deletes last number. i.e: 42235 -> 4223 
}
```

This makes `a` an array with each `a[i]` (the ith position) containing the number of times the digit `i` appears on the number. For example, with `n1 = 1233210346576`, `a` would be `{1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0}`

Then, the following part does the same but decreasing the array. Our number is a permutation iff `a` is an array of 0s once again.

For the second one, honestly i don't get it... If a for loop can be broken into 5 clauses, i didn't know... But basically, you want to compare the ith letter from the left and the ith letter from the right, with i going from the first one to half the total amount. With maybe some +-1s here and there to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

- In `is_permutation_division` function,

  ```
  //assume n1 = 237654, n2 = 743526

  int is_permutation_division (unsigned long n1, unsigned long n2)
  {
  int a[10]  =  {0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0};
  //             ^   ^   ^   ^   ^   ^   ^   ^   ^   ^
  //calc num of '0' '1' '2' '3' '4' '5' '6' '7' '8' '9' symbols of n1
  size_t i;

  while (n1 != 0)
  {
      a[n1 % 10]++; //a[0] keeps num of '0', a[1] keeps num of '1',...of n1
      n1 /= 10;
  }// now, a[] = {0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0}, for n1 = 237654

  while (n2 != 0)
  {
      a[n2 %10]--;// to check the count of '0','1','2'... of n2 
      n2 /= 10;
  }//now, a[] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}, since n2 = 743526
   //because, n2 has the same digital symbol array, 
   //all elements of a[] would be 0 by count back

  for (i=0; i<10; i++)
  {
      if (a[i] != 0)
      {
          return 0;//if there is a non zero element, not permutation, return
      }
  }// now, a[] is full of 0
  return 1;//then n2 is permutation of n1 
  }
  ```
- In `is_palindrome` function,

  `for (i=0; j<strlen(s); i<j; i++; j--)`// some problems here

  it should be:

  `for (i=0, j = strlen(s); i<j; i++, j--)`